# Enum in an Entity Framework POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I have the following employee class and employee status enum:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClockNo { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EmployeeStatus Status { get; set; }


}

public enum EmployeeStatus : int
{
    New = 1,
    Experienced = 2,
    Terminated = 3

}
```

I only want the enum made available to the Employee class so I tried nesting it:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClockNo { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EmployeeStatus Status { get; set; }

    enum EmployeeStatus : int
    {
        New = 1,
        Experienced = 2,
        Terminated = 3

    }         

}
```

I get a compile time error of EmployeeStatus could not be found.  How do I approach this problem ?  I want my employee status to be limited to a set of options that I hard code and that intellisense makes available to me.

[image]

Comment: "I get a compile time error of EmployeeStatus could not be found." -- No, you didn't, at least not for the code you posted. The code you posted will give a different error, and that different error has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: I added my error in the original post above.

Comment: You do get a file name and line number for that error message, don't you? It won't be in what you posted. (Dan-o's answer addresses the error message you should be getting for what you did post.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest the enum in the class unless you make the enum public.  Making the enum private like you have, while surfacing it via a public property (`public EmployeeStatus Status { get; set; }`) will cause this error.

Either make the enum public, or make the property private.